# How to update to an array if element already exists

Tags: arrays, react-native, ecmascript-6, setstate

I'm making a React-Native application. Thanks to everyone's help I could somehow make that work except for toggling YES and NO. Once the user clicks on a button I just want to check if that clicked item data already exists in the state, if so I want to update it. If it does not exist then it should be added to the state as a new Item.

I already coded the above logic, my code is working, but not returning correct output, elements are not adding or updating to the state array properly. How do I fix this code?

I want to generate output like this

```
[{
  chelistid:231,
  validiary : "YES",
  remark : "Hello"
},{
  chelistid:232,
  validiary : "NO",
  remark : "asddddd"
}]
```

**My code**

```
const [reqData, setReqData] = useState([]);

//Modify yes clicked
    const yesClicked = (element) => {
        let req = {
            "chelistid": element.chelistid,
            "validiary": "Yes",
            "remark": element.remark
        }
        createCheckList(req);
    }

    //Modify no clicked
    const noClicked = (element) => {
        let req = {
            "chelistid": element.chelistid,
            "validiary": "No",
            "remark": element.remark
        }
        createCheckList(req);
    }

    const createCheckList = (data) => {
        const index = reqData.findIndex(x => x.chelistid === data.chelistid)
        var modifiedArray = reqData
        if (index !== -1) {
            //Remove the element from the array
            modifiedArray.splice(index, 1);
        }
        setReqData([modifiedArray, data]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is it seems like you are not spreading the array to append the data element. What you are doing by `[modifiedArray, data]` you are creating an array that contains an array and data something like `[[modified array content here], data]`. But actually, you want to append to modified array instead. For that, you need to expand the modified array by using `...` which is called spread syntax. ([Learn here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)) So, your code would look like:

```
        setReqData([...modifiedArray, data]);
```